# Avoiding Redundant Class Generation with jaxws-maven-plugin for Shared XSDs in Multiple WSDLs

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm working on a Java project where I need to create classes for WSDL and XSD files using the `jaxws-maven-plugin`. My challenge is that I'm ending up with redundant classes. This issue arises because both of my WSDL files (`Foo.wsdl` and `Bar.wsdl`) use the same XSD files (`Commons.xsd` and `Errors.xsd`).

I'm looking for a way to generate classes for `Commons.xsd` and `Errors.xsd` only once and then reuse them across my WSDL files. Below is the structure of my Java resources folder and the current configuration of my plugin:

Java Resources Folder Structure:

```
src/main/resources/wsdl/
├── Foo
│   ├── Foo.wsdl
│   ├── FooResponse.xsd
│   ├── FooRequest.xsd
│   ├── Commons.xsd
│   └── Errors.xsd
└── Bar
    ├── Bar.wsdl
    ├── BarResponse.xsd
    ├── BarRequest.xsd
    ├── Commons.xsd
    └── Errors.xsd
```

Plugin Configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <destDir>${classesDir}</destDir>
        <sourceDestDir>${sourcesDir}</sourceDestDir>
        <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/*</wsdlLocation>
        <wsdlDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Foo</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <packageName>com.provider.schema.foo</packageName>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>Foo/Foo.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>Bar</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <packageName>com.provider.schema.bar</packageName>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>Bar/Bar.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Example of XSD import in WSDL:

```xml
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.provider.com/FOO">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.provider.com/schema" schemaLocation="FooResponse.xsd"/>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.provider.com/schema" schemaLocation="FooRequest.xsd"/>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.provider.com/schema" schemaLocation="Commons.xsd"/>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.provider.com/schema" schemaLocation="Errors.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

How can I efficiently generate the classes for shared XSD files without redundancy and ensure they are properly utilized by each WSDL?

I attempted to use a single execution with multiple WSDL files, but this resulted in the `ObjectFactory` being overwritten by the last WSDL file in the list.